Mobile Push SDK - silent push
We are implementing SFMC mobile push SDK and mobile dev are having an issue.

In android - push notification works only when the app is active.
when app is closed + in lockscreen - push notification is not received.
As per mobile dev - firebase fcm sends the notification as data message when app is not active.

They tested the Alert + inbox as well - and notification only triggered when app was active, when the app was closed - no notification was receive but message is available (silent)
As per mobile dev - they have reintegrated the app again using the documentation from SFMC mobile push SDK to resolve the issue but still the same.
What could be the possible reason?

Recently around 3 days ago - contacts registered to SFMC mobile push has started a delay latency of 1-2 days before it will display/registered in SFMC.

Tested today with the mobile devs and it took 6 hours before my contact key was available in SFMC all contacts.



As per devs - no change in the mobile app code has been implemented. It just happened and they though it might be SF issue.
But when I tested to register a new contact using the Android Learning app - it was available instantly in SFMC Contact list.
Hoping I could get some help/answer to these issues. Thank you.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. What you have is a story - a claim that something doesn't work. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

Noted on this @identigral.
I've asked the mobile app dev to share some code documentation for their implementation with mobile push SDK so I can scan it as well to help identify the issue,
as well as to provide additional information when asking support to resolve the issue.
Thank you

Open a support case.
